# how to handle more than one article then print out output in java

Tags: java, article

```
public class Print {

public static void handlewords() throws IOException {

    String path = "Dictionary.txt";
    String path1 = "training.txt";

    //read wordlist(dictionary)
    File file = new File(path2);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
    // read the articles
    Features ft = new Features();
    String content = ft.readFile(path);
    String [] words = content.split(" ");

    StringBuffer bs = new StringBuffer();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path1);  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      bs.append(line+"\n");
    }
      br.close();
      String str = bs.toString();
      String [] word = str.split(" ");

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(words.length);
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(word.length);

   for(String s: words){
        list1.add(s);
    }

     for(String x: word){
        list2.add(x);
        HashSet set = new HashSet(list2);
            list2.clear();
            list2.addAll(set);
    }
   System.out.print("{");
    for(String x: list1){
        for(String y: list2){
            if(x.equalsIgnoreCase(y)){
               System.out.print(list1.indexOf(x));
            }
        }

    }
        System.out.print("}");
}

}
```

My purpose is to check if the word in article what is also in the dictionary and print it out the position. I have done to deal with one article, but I am stuck in to handle couple of articles in my training.txt file.
My training file looks like this:

1."I am programming ......" -----This is the first article

2."I am programming too...." -----This is the second article.

n. "............." -----This is the nth article.
My code works for one article, but how to handle more than one article?
The output should be:

1. {2 5 6 7}
2. {1 3 4}
3. ......

Comment: Create an Array of Strings that contains the filepaths. Put the rest of your code in a for loop, and use a new path every iteration.

Comment: Thank you, but all the articles should be in one file.